# CORS issue with Office JS Excel Task Pane and React (webpack)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, office-addins

I have an CORS issue wwhen I try on click to call some endpoint

```
click = async () => {
  try {
    var response = null;
    let config = {
      method: 'get',
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      url: 'https://demoefaktura.mfin.gov.rs/api/publicApi/get-unit-measures',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'ApiKey': '123456'
      }
    };

    axios.request(config)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status != 200) {
        throw new Error("Bad response from server");
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })


  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

It returns a CORS error.
When I try to hit this endpoint through postman, it returns OK result.

Mine application is auto-generated by the manual from learn.microsoft.com and I generated it with Yeoman generator `yo office` then I choose react framework for Excel add-in.

By default, webpack rises application (addin Task Pane) on localhost:3000 and I assume that different port causes this error.

Approach #1: I tried to put in my manifest.xml source url as

```
<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://demoefaktura.mfin.gov.rs/</AppDomain>
  <AppDomains>
```

It didn't help.

Approach #2: I need somehow to tell my app to buold it on port 80 but Im not sure how?
Approach #3 is to use another node server as CORS resolver, but Im not sure how to do it?

It should be straight forward, when it runs an app (excel add-in) to be able to ping some endpoint, but this is major obstacle in my case.

Any ideas?

Thanks